# In tutorial of ethereum zokrates, high-level code compile error

Tags: zokrates

im trying to follow this tutorial
 - https://zokrates.github.io/sha256example.html

I built zokrates docker provided and copied the source code to the docker, and then tried to compile the code.

here is the code:

```
import "LIBSNARK/sha256packed"
def main(private field a, private field b, private field c, private field d) -> (field[2]):
h = sha256packed([a,b,c,d])
    return h
```

However, i faced following error messages:

> Compilation failed: Semantic error: Function definition for function sha256packed with signature (field[4]) -> (_) not found.

what is wrong with this work?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an old answer by now, but I believe you were looking at an outdated version of the blog. ZoKrates have modified the SHA256 gadget, and the import now looks liek this:

`import "hashes/sha256/512bitPacked.code" as sha256packed`

The function signature also is a bit different now that what it was, but your code already seems to conform to the current version.